# Does "Money Plus Sunset" cope with data files from the UK versions of Microsoft Money?

Tags: microsoft-money

I know that the US and UK version of money had problems reading each other’s files, does Money Plus Sunset cope with files from the UK version?

If not, are their any workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

An option is to download the [Money 2005 UK - QFE2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26915) from Microsoft - this provides the last UK version of Money.

Comment: This link is now broken.

Answer (score 1):

Money Plus Sunset can't open UK edition Money data files.  See Glyn Simpson's article ["How to export/import accounts (using QIF)"](http://money.mvps.org/faq/article/28.aspx).  See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Money for how to get online services in Money Plus Sunset.